# Floating imageview with text and buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am loading images from a db to `listview` and I want to create a floating window. Once one of them is clicked the floating window pic is attached.

I know how to handle `onClick` events from a list but I can't find a way to create the activity layout correctly

[image]

And this is what I came up so far -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_dialog_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ab" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/open_in_other_app"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="button2" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: an alert dialog with custom layout will accomplish this task

Comment: TNX that really helps!

Comment: good :) all the best ~

Answer (score 2):

With @twntee advice and some serach I got to this articale which solved my problem - 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/